# id3 tag encoding problem in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, id3, id3-tag

I'm now extracting id3 tags from MP3 files in my php page with the help of getid3 library, which is a lib extracting id3 tags written in php. Something really wired is that part of the metadata is in Chinese or Russian. When those kind of tags are encountered, the characters can't be encoded correctly. Things go well if tags are English.

I think this must be something related to encoding problem. How can I detect how the id3 tags are encoded and how to echo the right character out?

Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the `mb-detect-encoding` php function. See php.net. Depending on your needs, you could `mb_convert_encoding` to convert tags to a common encoding to be saved back to the files.